# Java: given a HashMap, how can I use containsKey() to tell if key is explicitly mapped to a null value?

Tags: java

I am currently learning Java and running into some trouble with simple Java code where I have to deal with a HashMap that has missing keys and values.

Specifically, I am looking for an way to distinguish between the following two cases given a HashMap `myHashMap`:

1. `myHashMap.get("myKey")` is explicitly mapped to `null`
2. `myHashMap` does not contain an key for `"myKey"`

In looking around for a solution, I found the following in [documentation for the `get` method for HashMaps in Java 8 SE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-), which says that:

> A return value of null does not necessarily indicate that the map contains no mapping for the key; it's also possible that the map
>   explicitly maps the key to null. The `containsKey` operation may be used
>   to distinguish these two cases.

**I am wondering if someone knows how I could use containsKey() in this way?**

Comment: If `containsKey` is true, use `get` to determine if the key is mapped to a `null`?

Comment: It's hard to know where you're running into trouble, since `containsKey` is so self explanatory.  Where are you having trouble when you tried to use it or read the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) myHashMap.get("myKey") is explicitly mapped to null

Even though it mapped to `null`, still containsKey return `true` for you because there is a key called `myKey` exists holding a value `null`

> 2)myHashMap does not contain an key for "myKey"

That obviously return `false`, Since no key found with that name.

Comment: I downvoted because your initial answer had nothing to do with the question.  I'll remove it now.  If you want to avoid downvotes like that in the future, try not to use placeholder answers without reading the question first.  There's nothing useful to the community about gaming the system in that way.

Comment: @MarkPeters Thank you :) Initially I didn't care about down vote on my answer. But there are 2 more down votes on @ ruakh and @ djechlin answers and no comment at least which is weird. That makes me comment :)

Answer (score 0):

There's not much more to explain, but here's an explicit code sample.

```
HashMap<Integer, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put(1, new Object());
m.containsKey(1); // returns true
m.containsKey(2); // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish the three possibilities (not mapped to anything vs. explicitly mapped to null vs. mapped to a non-null value) like this:

```
final boolean keyIsNotMappedToAnything =
    !myHashMap.containsKey("myKey");

final boolean keyIsExplicitlyMappedToNull =
    myHashMap.containsKey("myKey") && myHashMap.get("myKey") == null;

final boolean keyIsMappedToANonNullValue =
    myHashMap.get("myKey") != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the contain key method

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073473/java-map-get-and-map-containskey.html